# Laravel does not read env variables

Tags: laravel, environment-variables, laravel-artisan

Did anyone has issues with `env` variables? For some reason, helper `env('VARIABLE')` returns `null` every time I use it. It happened very unexpectedly and I dont really know the reason. Restarting the apache/IDE/computer does not work.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The solution is simple, but neither the IDE nor the debugger says anything about it. It just returns `null`. When you use `php artisan config:cache`, according to the documentation:

> If you execute `php artisan config:cache`command during your deployment process, you should be sure that you are only calling the `env()` function from **within** your configuration files.

Obviously I have `env` variables outside the config files, so after caching I was not able to use it outside anymore. The `php artisan config:clear` puts it back to work.

What I've found more about the usage of `env`, that it should be used **only** within config files. You can access `env` variables from the rest of the project using other helper method `config()`. Be sure to assign it to another key in config file, e.g. `'key' => env('CACHE_DRIVER')`

What is more, you have to remember to run `php artisan config:cache` each time you will change `.env` file. Laravel will not load the new values, until it's cached. If it's not cached, no need to do it.

Answer (score 53):

Run those of command

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

Now try to read

```
$value = env('VARIABLE_NAME');
```

if not working till now then,

Try **another syntax** to read env variable.

```
$value=getenv('VARIABLE_NAME');
```

Comment: Tip: clear all kinds of cache at once. Just run "php artisan optimize:clear"

Answer (score 6):

please use this its work for me use git bash or cmd and past this command

```
$ rm bootstrap/cache/config.php
```

this command clear cache folder

Answer (score 5):

Just run

```
php artisan config:clear
```

It solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it's just because I'm using `php artisan serve`, just restart it, the server command may read the env and keep at the startup time.